# Disable special characters such as Tilde (German keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I am using my Mac to write Java code in Eclipse. Not frequently, but commonly enough I need special characters such as ^, ~ or `.
The problem with these is that I have to press the key(-combination) followed by a space in order to insert the character, since these keys are used to create special characters such as ã or è. However, this is really impractical since I can't use them in Java anyway.

Is there a way to disable this feature globally on OS X Yosemite (german keyboard layout)?

Comment: So, for example, you want option + n to produce tilde right away without a space being required?

Comment: Exactly. Pressing Option+n generates an 'underlined' tilde character, and pressing another key such as 'a' replaces the underlined tilde with 'ã'.

Comment: I don't know any way to disable that except by creating a custom keyboard layout.  The apps for that are Ukelele and Karabiner.  You could do text replacement entries in system prefs/keyboard/text, but that would normally still require an extra space.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change input source. Probably you have U.S. International, just change it U.S. and this ugly feature will disappear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Thanks your for answer, but the OP states in the question that the keyboard layout is German.

Comment: Simply switching to *US* -- not to be confused with the _US International_ -- keyboard layout fixes this for me. My physical keyboard is also German but I've always used the US layout for programming.

Comment: thanks man, I just switched to the "US" input source and the problem seems fixed now. I had selected "US International" before and the problem was persisting and I was losing some brain cells over it.